# How to install third party jar into maven repo using eclipse only?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I want install a jar named `qrgen 1.4` in maven repo.I tried using it as a depedency but that does not work as maven version of that jar is not available.I have tried writing like this [image]

But i get error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) on project primedemop: The artifact information is incomplete or not valid:
[ERROR] [0]  'groupId' is missing.
[ERROR] [1]  'artifactId' is missing.
[ERROR] [2]  'packaging' is missing.
[ERROR] [3]  'version' is missing.
```

Please tell how to do it?

Comment: why not with native `mvn` call, this interface from eclipse probably only operates on the pom.xml of that project

Comment: I don't using command line when i write mvn install i get error liek 'mvn install' is not external or internal command.I know beacause i have not set the path in eneviorment variable.But i don't how to get the path of maven which is in my eclipse ide @JigarJoshi

Comment: maven has a singleton local cache where you would end up installing, so it doesn't matter if it is eclipse's mvn or external maven, you could set up path

Comment: how do i get the path of installed maven do in need to set path like i do for java like path till bin folder ???@JigarJoshi

Comment: google how to setup `PATH` for your operating system